# How Well is a US College Degree Accepted in Québec?

Tags: masters, application, united-states

Though originally a Québecker, I am soon to graduate in the United States with a bachelor's in Computer Information Systems, and a bachelor's in Graphic Design, from a college accredited by [TRACS](https://tracs.org/). I intend to pursue a master's related to informatics (not possible at my current college). I want to study in my home province because of the additional language and lower tuition fees.

Québec tends to be very specific with college requirements; I cannot apply until December, when I graduate, but was wondering whether I would be accepted easily, or whether this will be a nightmare. I checked l'UQÀM, for example, and [their requirements state specific Québec degrees, or two years of applicable work experience with a trained background.](https://etudier.uqam.ca/programme?code=3281#bloc_conditions) Université Laval [requires having completed equivalent training [to an undergraduate degree] according to the acceptance committee.](https://etudier.uqam.ca/programme?code=3281#bloc_conditions) These requirements are a little nebulous, as they could go either way.

I have contacted Université Laval previously, but they cannot be more specific before I apply. Was wondering whether anyone else has experience transferring in this way, or otherwise general advice for avoiding catch-up coursework.

Comment: It's worth noting for everyone that TRACS is *not* one of the traditional regional accreditation bodies in US higher education.  It *is* one of the accreditation bodies recognized by the Department of Education, but many believe that the national accreditation bodies have laxer criteria for accreditation, to the extent that their degrees may not be recognized.

Comment: There is no way of knowing without someone seeing the actual application file.  The decision is likely done on a case by case basis.   Expect make-up courses.

Comment: Answering my question, I have applied to the university in question and been accepted without difficulty regarding my education. Happily, in my particular case, makeup has not been cited as a condition for completion.

Answer (score 4):

A US Bachelors degree generally would be accepted, but in your case, since your degree is from a TRACS accredited college, you may have a difficult time.

For my US university (and most US universities), the policy for domestic applicants for graduate studies states:

> Students must have a bachelor’s degree from a college or university
> accredited by a regional accrediting association. If the degree is
> from a recognized but not regionally accredited institution, the
> application will be reviewed by the department and by the College of
> Graduate Studies.

TRACS is NOT a regional accrediting association.  Without more details, it's not clear whether your college would qualify under the second sentence, but note that it already states further special review is necessary.

Given that your degree would not be recognized by most universities in the US (or at least not automatically), you will likely have a difficult time having your degree recognized in other countries.

Comment: This does clarify, but IDK how much Québec cares about American accreditation.

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque I think you're basically in a spot where you apply and hope they don't care (or don't notice) that you have a quite questionable US degree - that quality probably matters a lot more than whether your degree is from the US.

Comment: They have to care about something, because in most US states it's perfectly legal for anyone to start Joe's College and start awarding degrees to anyone willing to pay $20.  Of course no one will recognize degrees from Joe's College as meaning anything.

Comment: The belief that local accreditations are better perhaps stems from the fact that local colleges/universities know each other's programs, and therefore are better prepared for student transfers than institutions which are far apart. In theory, this may not prevent students from transferring between non-local institutions, but could make it more arduous?

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque - No.  It's because, generally speaking and with a slight bit of exaggeration, the national accreditors will give accreditation to anyone claiming to be a university who is willing to give them $20K.  The regional accreditors actually have standards a university is expected to meet before they accredit it.  The fact that it's the regional accreditors who happen to have high standards is essentially a historical quirk.